# How to post the data in Node js

Tags: node.js

In my application i need to post the dynamic data into my main page(mani page means if i run my url(localhost:3456) in browser means that will display one page na that page).How can i post that data.I have tried this but i couldn't post the data.Can anyone help me to fix the issue.

app.js

```
     var http = require('http');
     var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
                  res.writeHead(200, ['Content-Type', 'text/plain']);
                  res.write('Hello ');
                  res.end('World');
                   });
     server.listen(3456);
```

postdata.js

```
 var data={"errorMsg":{"errno":34,"code":"ENOENT","path":"missingFile.txt"},"date":"2013-0402T11:50:22.167Z"}
 var options = {
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 3456,
                path: '/',
                method: 'POST',
                data:data,
                header: {
                           'content-type': 'application/json', 
                           'content-length': data.length       
                         }
                 };

 var http=require('http');
 var req;
 req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    var body;
    body = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    body += chunk;
  });
 return res.on('end', function() {
    console.log('body is '+body);
  });
  });
 req.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);

});

 req.write(data);
 req.end();
```

Comment: It would be much appreciated if you would take the time to format your code in a readable way (correct indentation) before asking others for help.

Comment: @BretCopeland hi i have formatted my code.Please check this one

Answer (score -1):

Do you have express installed along with Node, if so you can set up Rest Api's which you can use them in your jQuery and bind data dynamically. Please try to look into 
http://expressjs.com/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Two things. First:

```
var data={"errorMsg:{"errno":34,"code":"ENOENT","path":"missingFile.txt"},"date":"2013-0402T11:50:22.167Z"}
```

is missing a double-quote, so it's invalid syntax... hence why the syntax highlighting is having trouble.

Second:

```
req.write(data);
```

should be:

```
req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, I think you might be asking how to read from the body of an HTTP POST request (you're question is very ambiguously worded). If so, that's already very well documented in the Node.js API. Something along the lines of:

```
var server = http.createServer(requestHandler);
server.listen(3456);

function requestHandler (req, res) {
    req.setEncoding('utf8');
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function (chunk) { body += chunk; });
    req.on('end', function () {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('The body of your request was: ' + body);
    });
}
```

If that's not what you're asking, you'll need to clarify your question. Terms like 'main page' have no meaning unless you explicitly define what they are and what the expected outcome is.

Comment: hi while copying my code i did some mistake my data is {"errorMsg":{"errno":34,"code":"ENOENT","path":"missingFile.txt"},"date":"2013-04-03T05:29:15.521Z"} its already converted into JSON string.I need to display this JSON string in my main html page how can i do that.

Comment: mani page means if i run my url(localhost:3456) in browser means that will display one page na that page.

Answer (score -1):

```
//this is a string
var jsonString = '{"errorMsg":{"errno":34,"code":"ENOENT","path":"missingFile.txt"},"date":"2013-04-03T05:29:15.521Z"}';

//this is an object
var jsonObj = {"errorMsg":{"errno":34,"code":"ENOENT","path":"missingFile.txt"},"date":"2013-04-03T05:29:15.521Z"};
```

*note the single quotes in for string*

`request.write(chunk, [encoding])` requires chunk to be either Buffer or string (see: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_write_chunk_encoding)